# Nested Virtualization KVM: entry failed, hardware error 0x7

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm

I have a VM on a host and want to create another VM within the existing VM (nested).

- Host: opensuse Tumbleweed, kernel 4.19.7, 96 CPUS Intel-Xeon, 256GB RAM (nested virt enabled in kvm)
- L1 VM: opensuse Leap, kernel 4.12.14, 4 vCPUS, 8 GB RAM
- L2 VM: opensuse Leap, 1 vCPU, 1GB RAM

Virtalization on L1 VM is apparently enabled:

```
$ virt-host-validate 
  QEMU: Checking for hardware virtualization                                 : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/kvm exists                                   : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/kvm is accessible                            : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/vhost-net exists                             : PASS
  QEMU: Checking if device /dev/net/tun exists                               : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller support                         : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller support                     : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support                      : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support                      : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS
  QEMU: Checking for device assignment IOMMU support                         : WARN (No ACPI DMAR table found, IOMMU either disabled in BIOS or not supported by this hardware platform)
   LXC: Checking for Linux >= 2.6.26                                         : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace ipc                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace mnt                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace pid                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace uts                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace net                                           : PASS
   LXC: Checking for namespace user                                          : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpu' controller support                         : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuacct' controller support                     : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'cpuset' controller support                      : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'memory' controller support                      : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'devices' controller support                     : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'freezer' controller support                     : PASS
   LXC: Checking for cgroup 'blkio' controller support                       : PASS
   LXC: Checking if device /sys/fs/fuse/connections exists                   : PASS
```

And lscpu shows vmx flag:

```
 $ lscpu 
    Architecture:        x86_64
    CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
    Byte Order:          Little Endian
    CPU(s):              4
    On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
    Thread(s) per core:  1
    Core(s) per socket:  1
    Socket(s):           4
    NUMA node(s):        1
    Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               79
    Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7-8890 v4 @ 2.20GHz
    Stepping:            1
    CPU MHz:             2194.710
    BogoMIPS:            4389.42
    Virtualization:      VT-x
    Hypervisor vendor:   KVM
    Virtualization type: full
    L1d cache:           32K
    L1i cache:           32K
    L2 cache:            4096K
    L3 cache:            16384K
    NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl xtopology cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch topoext cpuid_fault invpcid_single pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm rdseed adx smap xsaveopt arat umip
```

After creating a VM, it goes to paused mode and can't be resumed.

```
$ virsh list --all
 Id   Name   State
---------------------
 3    myvm   paused

$ virsh resume myvm
error: Failed to resume domain myvm
error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'cont': Resetting the Virtual Machine is required
```

This is the qemu log showing some problem with kvm, hardware error 0x7.

```
$ cat /var/log/libvirt/qemu/myvm.log 
2018-12-19 15:34:27.814+0000: starting up libvirt version: 4.10.0, qemu version: 3.0.95openSUSE Leap 15.1, kernel: 4.12.14-lp151.19-default, hostname: susetest
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=spice /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -name guest=myvm,debug-threads=on -S -object secret,id=masterKey0,format=raw,file=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-3-myvm/master-key.aes -machine pc-i440fx-3.1,accel=kvm,usb=off,dump-guest-core=off -m 1024 -realtime mlock=off -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 -uuid ff9104ff-4992-4747-bbd4-33c8517a9570 -no-user-config -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=24,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc -no-shutdown -boot strict=on -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2 -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/mydisk.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0 -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 -netdev tap,fd=26,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=27 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=be:a6:22:ed:1a:7b,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -chardev pty,id=charchannel0 -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=org.qemu.guest_agent.0 -chardev pty,id=charconsole1 -device virtconsole,chardev=charconsole1,id=console1 -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing,seamless-migration=on -device cirrus-vga,id=video0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6 -object rng-random,id=objrng0,filename=/dev/random -device virtio-rng-pci,rng=objrng0,id=rng0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7 -sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny -msg timestamp=on
char device redirected to /dev/pts/1 (label charserial0)
char device redirected to /dev/pts/2 (label charchannel0)
char device redirected to /dev/pts/3 (label charconsole1)
KVM: entry failed, hardware error 0x7
```

Comment: Error code 7 means VM entry with an invalid control field in the VMCS. Possibly because the nested KVM is trying to use a VMX feature that the root VMM doesn’t support.

Comment: Because this is posted on stackoverflow, I have been thinking about how to advise you to debug it, but on further reflection, probably you would be better off posting to superuser.com.

Comment: If you do want to debug it, my first step would be to find out whether the error is being reported by the CPU or by KVM. Normally this error is reported by the CPU when VM entry is attempted, but in the nested case, it may be detected and reported by the code in KVM that handles VM entry to a sub-guest.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, the error message is coming from QEMU, but it is reporting an error code that it got from KVM. KVM, in turn, got the error code from the hardware, or in the nested virtualization case, from the virtualized hardware, which is implemented by the root KVM. The root KVM may have detected and reported the error itself, or it may have passed on an error code that it got from the real hardware while trying to enter the nested VM.

Comment: It's actually easier to figure out the problem if the error is being detected by KVM, since we can debug the code and figure out which check is failing. If the error is being detected by the CPU, it can be hard to determine exactly what it is complaining about.

Comment: I was doing some tests and I get he same error when I use directly the qemu command with flag "-enable-kvm" but it works when I remove the flag.

Comment: e.g. /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -hda autoboot.qcow2  WORKS
but 
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm  -hda autoboot.qcow2  FAILS

Comment: I'd recommend posting this to the upstream mailing lists: kvm@vger.kernel.org. It's a pretty friendly space, and they should know which clarifying questions to ask. Note that Nested is being actively developed, so you may want to fetch a 4.20 kernel for l0.

If you want to debug this yourself, try running the kvm-unit-tests in both L0 and L1 (https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/virt/kvm/kvm-unit-tests.git/).